# Build multiple images from one Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to work with multiple images from a single Dockerfile.  The following succeeds when `docker compose build` is run, but I notice in the layers that both images have `ENV KEY2=VALUE2`.  I am expecting image1 to have `ENV KEY1=VALUE1`.

What am I missing?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:23.04 AS image1
ENV KEY1=VALUE1

FROM ubuntu:23.04 AS image2
ENV KEY2=VALUE2
```

compose.yaml:

```
services:
  service1:
    container_name: container1
    build: .
    image: image1
  service2:
    container_name: container2
    build: .
    image: image2
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#image) describes the following behavior when you use `image` in the docker compose file:

> If the image does not exist, Compose attempts to pull it, unless you have also specified build, in which case it builds it using the specified options and tags it with the specified tag.

so the `Dockerfile` is built and indeed it is tagged with `image1`, however given the multi-stage build nature of the `Dockerfile` you end up only with everything following the second `FROM`.

Use separate Dockerfiles for the two images.

Answer (score 0):

Added after comment :

Then you better to create two Dockerfiles and use them in `docker-compose`

docker-file1.yaml

```
FROM ubuntu:23.04 AS image1
ENV KEY1=VALUE1
```

docker-file2.yaml

```
FROM ubuntu:23.04 AS image2
ENV KEY2=VALUE2
```

You docker-compose file :

```
services:
  service1:
    container_name: container1
    build: docker-file1.yaml
    image: image1
  service2:
    container_name: container2
    build: docker-file2.yaml
    image: image2
```

Comment: The `ENV` lines where just intended as single lines where each would only show up in one of the images.  Having said that, the RUN lines that you put cause `docker compose build` to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are [not shared by default across stages](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/docker-copy-variables-stages) in multi-stage Dockerfiles. However, as others have pointed out in the comments, behaviour is likely different when building via docker compose.

If you intend to share the Dockerfile between the two images, and the only differences between the two are a few variables, you should use the args sub-option:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:23.04
ARG MY_VAR
ENV KEY1 $MY_VAR
```

**Docker Compose**

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  args:
    - MY_VAR=value1
```

But if the images have different setups, you should use two separate Dockerfiles.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it, and it works.

Please create 2 dockerfiles.

Dockerfile1:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 AS image1
ENV KEY1=VALUE1
```

Dockerfile2:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 AS image2
ENV KEY2=VALUE2
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  service1:
    container_name: container1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile1
    image: image1
  service2:
    container_name: container2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile2
    image: image2
```

To see env in service1: **docker-compose run service1 env**

[image]

Comment: I wonder if `docker-compose run service1 env` would be a simpler way to run this setup; you should almost never need a no-op `tail` command "to keep the container running".  Can you [edit] the answer to show the `env` output in plain text rather than an image (it will be smaller, more readable, more accessible, and more searchable)?

Comment: @DavidMaze,  I edited, thanks. Short and readable.